# How could I add a line in a Chart created from a Dynamic Table?

Tags: excel, charts, timeserieschart, dynamic-tables, vba

I've generated a Chart from a Pivot Table. I want to add a line (with a Series object for example), but no way.

I've tried things like that:

```
Sub createNewLineInChart()
    Dim cht As ChartObject
    Set cht = Sheets("mySlide").ChartObjects("myChart")
    cht.Chart.SeriesCollection.Add Source:=Sheets("mySlide").Range("a1:a5")
End Sub
```

While this works with "normal" Charts, it doesn't work with Charts generated from Pivot Table (my case). I need the data for the Chart comes from the Pivot Table, so to copy the data in a static table is not a solution.

So the question: are there any method to add a line in a dynamic generated Chart?

**EDIT:**

With "Dynamic Table" I mean Pivot Table

Comment: Please define `dynamic tables`? ...it could mean a number  of things depending on one's interpretation.

Comment: Sorry, I mean Pivot Tables. I'll edit the Question.